# How do I remove a SUB ( HEX: 1A ) control character in Java using regular expressions?

Tags: java, regex

I have a file with bad data in it (a few random SUB control characters that are by themselves... they are not part of a grapheme) and I was trying to remove them using a regex search pattern:

```
Text to Find: \x1a
Replace with:
```

This removes my SUB characters, but it is also messing up my other characters that have accents (é and í specifically).

Is there a regular expression out there that will remove the SUB control character (code point) if it is by itself?  (e.g. not part of a grapheme)

SAMPLE DATA (replace everywhere you see "␚" with the SUB control character:

```
A,André,Fernandez
A,Daniel,O␚Shea
A,Ibhlín,Flanders
A,Donny,O␚'Donnell
A,Spencer,O'Maley
```

SAMPLE DATA Output if I use my current regex:

```
A,Andr�,Fernandez
A,Daniel,OShea
A,Ibhl�n,Flanders
A,Donny,O'Donnell
A,Spencer,O'Maley
```

DESIRED DATA OUTPUT

```
A,André,Fernandez
A,Daniel,OShea
A,Ibhlín,Flanders
A,Donny,O'Donnell
A,Spencer,O'Maley
```

Comment: What is the Java code you're using to do the replacement?  Are you sure that the problem is with the regex replacement and not with the program that tries to display it?  In the Fernandez example, if you say `System.out.println((int)s.charAt(6))`, where `s` is the result string, what does it display?

Comment: Your code worked -- it removed the `sub` characters.  The problem is you changed the data stream encoding in the process of reading and writing the data, which is completely unrelated to the regular expressions.

Comment: Have you tried something like `output = input.replace("\u001b", "");`?

Comment: @JimGarrison - You're RIGHT!  It was the encoding!  My regex works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jim Garrison's comment is the answer:  The regex is properly removing the sub, but the encoding is changing in the process.

Also, I'm using a product call Boomi and I was using the built-in "Search/Replace" feature in Boomi.  Underneath the hood it is running Java, so that is why I did not answer ajb's question about the Java code since I didn't know the exact code that is being run.

The way we are getting around this issue is we are going to look at writing some custom Java code to do the character replacement instead of using Boomi's built-in Search/Replace feature.

THANK YOU for your help and pointing me in the right direction!

UPDATE: I just found a built-in feature in Boomi: Character Decode.  It turns out I can manage the encoding without writing custom Java code.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Position        Decimal        Name                     Appearance   
 0x241A          9242           SYMBOL FOR SUBSTITUTE    ␚
```

[unicode chart](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html%5d)

maybe this could help you.

Along with this.

[Regex Unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)